# Nginx returns blank page while serving Flutter DevTools with reverse proxy. (Ubuntu)

Tags: flutter, dart

When I access https://my.server.com, it returns blank page.
When I access http://myserver_external_ip:9100, it returns DevTools as expected.
I checked "my.server.com" by using Chrome DevTools, there was no error log.

```
server {
    server_name my.server.com; # my domain
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9100;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;

        }
    listen 443 ssl;
}

server {
    if ($host = my.server.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name my.server.com; # my domain
    return 404;
}
```

I think both urls return same pages.